# Is there a way to “hide” Vim’s interface to see the underlying shell?

Tags: vim

Something as light as buffer switching. So I can quickly jump there and back to check, for example, the output of the last `!`-invoked command.

I know there is the `:sh` command, but then you have to exit it to get back to Vim, so it is a bit heavy for the purpose.

I am also aware of http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window but I am not a huge fan of splits.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>, also accessible from the built in command `:suspend`.  Does that do what you want?

Comment: @das_weezul on MacOs `Ctrl-f` doesn't work, I use `fg`, is it possible to use `Ctrl-f` in MacOs terminal?

Comment: @jw013 yes, missed :) Found that we can emulate `Ctrl-f` in iTerm. Go to  `Settings > Profiles > Keys`, add shortcut for `Ctrl-f` and choose `Run Coprocess` from dropdown, then add `echo fg`. Maybe not the best solution but works smooth.

Comment: For zsh there is better solution: after adding to `.zshrc` this line `bindkey -s '^z' 'fg\n'` we can use `Ctrl-z` for back/forward in different terminals.

Comment: Fg shortcut bash: to `.bashrc` add `bind '"\C-f":"fg\n"'` for `Ctrl-f` (`Ctrl-z` is used by bash)

Answer (score 6):

If you do not mind *not* having scrolling, use

```
:!
```

(That is, run the `!` Ex command without arguments.)

Otherwise, if you are running the terminal version of Vim,
use `:suspend` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> (the latter
keyboard shortcut works in Normal and Visual modes).